# Replace sql column with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a problem with replacing a column in SQL script.

I have data like this (test.sql):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
  (ID,TEXT)
VALUES
 (1,'TEXT');

INSERT INTO TABLE
 (ID,TEXT)
VALUES
  (2,'TEXT242');

INSERT INTO TABLE
 (ID,TEXT)
VALUES
(3,'TEXT424242');
```

And I want to replace 'TEXT' on ID column with new value. This is ok, I can do something like this:

```
NEW="NEW"
grep 3 test.sql | awk -F "," -v OFS=, '{$2'$index'="'"'${NEW}'"'"; print }'
```

It will print:

```
(3,'NEW');
```

So, I have 2 problems:

1. I want to see all rows including the new one to change like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE
     (ID,TEXT)
   VALUES
    (1,'TEXT');

   INSERT INTO TABLE
     (ID,TEXT)
   VALUES
     (2,'TEXT242');

   INSERT INTO TABLE
     (ID,TEXT)
   VALUES
     (3,'NEW');
   ```
2. I want to have an exact match: so 3 is only 3 not 30 33...

Comment: Why don't you dump this SQL into a database and then use `select`/`update` statements to make your changes?  That seems as if it would have a much higher change of success than using `awk`.

Comment: It's difficult to explain but I can't :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to solve this *specific* problem (with no requirement to fully parse the statements and no variation in formatting), **`sed` enables an easier solution**:

**Update**: the OP has clarified that it is the *8th* column whose value should be replaced.

```
# Specify ID to match and replacement text.
id=3 new="NEW"

# Let `sed` perform the substitution. 
# `sed` outputs ALL lines by default, whether a substitution took place or not.
sed -E \
  "s/\($id(,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+),[^,]+(.*)/($id\1,'$new'\2/" \
  test.sql
```

As you can see `,[^,]+` is repeated 6 times inside `(...)` in order to capture the intervening column values - sadly, using `{6}` to repeat 6 times is not an option, because that would only capture the *last* instance of the pattern.

---

A **field-based `awk`** solution:

**Update**: the OP has clarified that it is the *8th* column whose value should be replaced.

This more flexible solution allows you to pass in the 1-based index of the target column as well. However, the assumption is that the ID column is always the *first*.

```
awk -F '[,()]' -v id=3 -v ndx=8 -v new="'NEW'" '
  $2==id {
    $(ndx+1)=new # replace the column value
     # Row has been rebuilt with just spaces as separators
     # output it in the original format.
    printf " (%s", id
    for (i=3;i<NF;++i) printf ",%s", $i
    print ");"
    next 
  }
  { print }
  ' test.sql
```

Note that the exact leading whitespace is not preserved.

Also note that since the input lines *start* with a field separator (`(` ), `awk` creates an extra, empty field at the beginning; therefore, the indices are incremented by 1.

---

To reiterate the caveat: in general, neither `awk` nor `sed` are the right tools for parsing SQL [DML] statements.

Comment: This sed seems good, but I forgotten to say, that the position can changed. This is why I used $index. Exactly is it at 8 position. It can be like this: (2,'NORMAL', 'NORM1, 'TEXTFORCHANGE', 'NORM'); But in real example is it at 8 position. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @user1089362: You should make that clearer in your question. I've updated my answer accordingly. The `awk` solution is now more flexible in that you can pass in a column index.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, but assumes that the data to replace doesn't have any apostrophes in it, and that the id to match is immediately followed by a comma:

```
awk -F"'" -v id=3 -v newval="${NEW}" 'NF==3 { print $1 FS ($1 ~ id",$" ? newval:$2) FS $3 } NF!=3 {print $0}' test.sql
```

the break down:

```
awk -F"'" -v id=3 -v newval="${NEW}" '
```

use `'` as the delimiter, sets up vars id and newval where newval is coming from bash

```
NF==3 { print $1 FS ($1 ~ id",$" ? newval:$2) FS $3 }
```

when there are 3 fields, print out either the existing second field or the newval if id matches.

```
NF!=3 {print $0}' test.sql
```

print out all other lines without adjustment.

when `NEW="JIVE"` outputs the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
  (ID,TEXT)
VALUES
 (30,'TEXT');

INSERT INTO TABLE
  (ID,TEXT)
VALUES
  (33,'TEXT242');

INSERT INTO TABLE
  (ID,TEXT)
VALUES
  (3,'JIVE');
```

where I replaced the original ids 1 and 2 with 30 and 33 to demonstrate it's only modifying the line you want.

---

Well, this got uglier, but here's a new 'one liner':

```
awk -F"'" -v id=3 -v newval="${NEW}" -v ind=$INDEX 'NF >= 2 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {fld=($1 ~ id",$" && i==ind) ? newval : $i; printf("%s%s", fld, (i==NF ? "\n" : FS) ) }} NF < 2{print}' test.sql
```

the break down:

```
awk -F"'" -v id=3 -v newval="${NEW}" -v ind=$INDEX '
```

In addition to the other variables, added an ind variable (`index` is a reserved function name).  Notice that the index is based on the `'` field separator.  In your comment, `$index` should be 6.

```
NF >= 2 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
```

Loop over all fields when there are more than two.

```
fld=($1 ~ id",$" && i==ind) ? newval : $i;
```

Set the output fields based on matching the id and the field index.

```
printf("%s%s", fld, (i==NF ? "\n" : FS) ) }}
```

Print out the current field and field separator, changing the final one into a newline.

```
NF < 2{print}' test.sql
```

Print out any remaining lines.

Comment: Seems good, but I forgotten to say, that the position can changed. This is why I used $index. Exactly is it at 8 position. It can be like this: (2,'NORMAL', 'NORM1, 'TEXTFORCHANGE', 'NORM'); But in real example is it at 8 position. Sorry for misunderstanding.